# Capturing level in multilevel BOM sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have the following query to capture a multi-level BOM. I now know all the child items for the parent but is there a way to capture the level as well in this query.

```
with mlBOM
AS (
   select bom_item_material_number, bom_item_component
   from BOM_TABLE bom
           where not exists (
      select *
      from BOM_TABLE BOM  inner join
      BOM_TABLE  BOM1
      on BOM1.bom_item_component = BOM.bom_item_material_number
    )
   union all 
   select  BOM.bom_item_material_number, 
   BOM.bom_item_component
   from BOM_TABLE  BOM
   inner join BOM_TABLE mlBOM on mlBOM.bom_item_component = BOM.bom_item_material_number
) select * 
from mlBOM 
;
```

Thanks,

Running on DBeaver Postgressql database

Answer (score 0):

You add an integer column that starts at `1` and increment it for each iteration:

```
with recursive mlbom as (
    select bom_item_material_number, bom_item_component, 1 lvl
    from bom_table bom
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from bom_table bom1 
        where bom1.bom_item_component = bom.bom_item_material_number
    )
   union all 
   select bom.bom_item_material_number, bom.bom_item_component, mlbom.lvl + 1
   from bom_table bom
   inner join mlbom on mlbom.bom_item_component = bom.bom_item_material_number
) 
select * from mlbom ;
```

I made a few fixes to the query:

- the cte declaration needs the `recursive` keyword
- there is no need to `join` in the `exists` subquery of the anchor of the recusive query
- presumably, the recursive part of the query oughts to join `bom` to `mlbom` instead of self-joining `bom`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer and the fixes. However when I run the query I get the following error: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column mlbom.lvl does not exist Position: 408. ( Although the lvl before the union is read as I tried inputting a random value instead of mlbom.lvl+1) –

Comment: @maheepajay: Postgres wants `recursive` in the cte declaration. I just fixed the query.

Comment: Thank you for the fix once again. Now I get the following SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "mlbom " does not exist
  Detail: There is a WITH item named "mlbom ", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
  Hint: Re-order the WITH items to remove forward references.

Comment: I believe the issue is with the greenplum+postgress not being able process the query properly